# ruby eval method is halting the displaying of UI form in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have written one helper method in rails that is populating the data in the select tag.

Data population in the select tag is done using eval method which evaluating some ruby code and after executing whatever data is returned from that ruby code it is then populated in the select_tag options.

My problem is in the UI form(select_tag and some  labels) is not getting displayed until the eval method completes its code execution, but my requirement is to display the form to the user first then using some ajax calls load the data in the select list.

As the data from which the select list is getting populating is in some text format present in some table so I have to use ruby eval method to execute that code.

But problem with eval is it halts the displaying of UI until it executes completely.

So is there any way using which I can accomplish the above task? let me know if any one has any approach to solve the above problem.

Thanks,
D

Comment: Ruby code of what you're trying here will be helpful to answer.

Comment: Here is sample code that I am using :

Comment: Here is sample code that I am using :http://pastie.org/private/lca8lunqufglwbiiw